# Define listings language using variable

Tags: macros, listings

I'm using the listings package to document excerpts from my programs. I have been creating new environments for the various programming languages and wondering whether there was a way to hack the package so that it accepts a variable for the language definition in `\lstset`.

For example,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\thelanguage}{Python}

\lstnewenvironment{\thelanguage}[1][]{
  \lstset{
    language = \thelanguage,
    #1
  }
}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{Python}
  This is a test.
\end{Python}
\end{document}
```

Using the above, latex throws the '!Improper alphabetic constant' error, which I presume is because the listings package is expecting a string rather than a variable. Is there a way round this? Should I be defining it as a macro and expanding it somehow? Still fairly new to latex, so any help would really help my understanding. Thanx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick tests show that the following modification to the `language` key-value setting function allows for proper expansion of macros used as languages:

```
\makeatletter
\lst@Key{language}\relax{\expandafter\lstKV@OptArg\expandafter[\expandafter]\expandafter{#1}%
    {\lst@LAS{language}{lang}{[##1]{##2}}\lst@FindAlias\lstlanguagefiles
         \lsthk@SetLanguage
         {\lst@FindAlias[##1]{##2}%
          \let\lst@language\lst@malias
          \let\lst@dialect\lst@oalias}}}
\makeatother
```

However, you would also require expansion of the macro passed to `\lstnewenvironment`. The following MWE shows how this is possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\makeatletter
\lst@Key{language}\relax{\expandafter\lstKV@OptArg\expandafter[\expandafter]\expandafter{#1}%
    {\lst@LAS{language}{lang}{[##1]{##2}}\lst@FindAlias\lstlanguagefiles
         \lsthk@SetLanguage
         {\lst@FindAlias[##1]{##2}%
          \let\lst@language\lst@malias
          \let\lst@dialect\lst@oalias}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\thelanguage}{Python}

\expandafter\lstnewenvironment\expandafter{\thelanguage}[1][]{
  \lstset{
    language = \thelanguage,
    #1
  }
}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{Python}
  This is a test.
\end{Python}
\end{document}
```

Although it may be considered to manipulate the language *and* environment using your approach (that is, use `\lstnewenvironment` and setting `language` using the same macro), it may seem cumbersome to manage this when working with different language dialects. For example, using

```
\newcommand{\thelanguage}{[XSC]Pascal}
```

would require you to use

```
\begin{[XSC]Pascal}
  %...
\end{[XSC]Pascal}
```

Comment: Agreed, this method could become cumbersome when using dialects. However, it's a good way to learn more about macros. Method above works. Thanks Werner.